# How To change value of a text box created dynamically through jquery append

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Hello i am creating a wordpress plugin where multiple file upload is required dynamically.
but i am not able to update the text value created by jquery append here is my code.

```
        <script>
        function uploadimage(imageid)
        {

                id="#imgfile"+imageid;

                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                 formfield = jQuery(id).attr('name');
                 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
                 return false;
                });

                window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
                 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
                 jQuery(id).val(imgurl); 
                 tb_remove();

                }
         }

        function countRows()
        {
        var oRows = document.getElementById('property').getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var i= oRows.length;

        return i;
        }

        function addRow()
        {
        var a= jQuery.noConflict();
        var i=countRows();

        var content="<tr><td>Image Link</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td class='controls'><input type='text' style='width:300px;' value='img1'  name='imgfile"+i+"' id='imgfile"+i+" '></td><td><input type='button' onClick='uploadimage("+i+")' value='upload'></td></tr>";
        document.getElementById('noOfRows').value=i;
        a('#property').append(content);
        }

        </script>



        <button type="button" onclick="addRow()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Image Url</button>
```

It works when i create the upload text box and button without append.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind `var a= jQuery.noConflict();`? You don't like `$`?

Comment: also I don't think you should be calling `noConflict` repeatedly.

Comment: Also calling `jQuery(document).ready` from within `uploadImage` seems strange at least. Normally you wrap the entire script into this and never touch it (or the browser's native DOM methods) again.

Comment: Also, "it doesn't work" is not very precise. It doesn't tell us anything (if it worked, you wouldn't be here).

Comment: no actually i had lot other jquery functions so to avoid conflict its there. You can remove it however.

Comment: `noConflict` is to prevent conflict with other libraries, not to let you use jQuery on more than one place.

Comment: The main problem i am facing is i am not able to update the imgurl generated to display in      jQuery(id).val(imgurl); note this is dynamically generated.

Comment: I will follow the thing about jQuery as you said am a bit new to this library.

Comment: Is `imageid` passed correctly?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `onX` attributes. You can attach a handler via [`$(...).on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: Yes i think so as i alerted it to check that. You can just help me with updating a dynamically generated textbox or send a link for same. i tried the jQuery Live function but couldn't do it.

Comment: I am trying to help you with that...

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan am cleaning the code as you said.

Comment: Try if removing `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` helps. At the point it is called the elements you are trying to access are already present, so no more waiting is neccessary.